# check two integer number in a string consecutive

Tags: javascript

i am doing a password validation where i need to check that two integer cant be together

ex: `aA@_1b55`

here i need 55 cant be there i have to throw an error

my function :

```
function checkBumber(password) {
        for (const i in password) {
             console.log('gdghb' , i);
             if (+password[+i + 1] === +password[i] + 1 && +password[+i + 2] === +password[i] + 2) {
                 this.data.pattern = true;
             }
         }
       
    }
```

Please Help!

Comment: like `/(\d)\1/.test(password)`?

Comment: or like /\d+/.test(password)? foo12 also forbidden, not just foo11?

Comment: Unrelated but please don't add this type of validations to passwords. It's very annoying and not useful in any way. Jeff Atwood's article on this: [Password Rules Are Bullshit](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/)

Comment: Explanation of your error : you are iterating over the _characters_, not on the _indexes_ of your string. If you want to use index, you should do something like `for (let i = 0; i < password.length - 2; i++)`

Comment: Re unlreated: ACK. only password rule making some (not full!) sense: minimal length

Comment: and... the obligatory relevant xkcd : https://xkcd.com/936/, to illustrate the point from LittleFox

Comment: @adiga i understand but have to do likr this :(

Comment: Understandable. Just mentioned it as an note, in case you are in a position to change the requirements or if it's your personal project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex and return false if the password matches the two successive number regex

`return !password.match(/\d{2}/)`

Comment: I thought that OP was forbidding only two times the same integer, like `55` is forbidden, but `56` is allowed. However, I am not sure now that I read the question description again. But if you read OP's code example, they are trying to test for equality of consecutive characters.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkBumber(password) {
    var check = true;

    for (i = 1; i < password.length; i++) {

        if (password.charAt(i) >= '0' && password.charAt(i) <= '9' && password.charAt(i) == password.charAt(i - 1)) check = false;
    }

    return check;
}
```